# unable to locate package ros-humble-desktop ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ros-humble

I am using ubuntu 20.04 and I am getting the error of unable to locate package when trying to install the ros 2 humble.

I followed the instructions on the ros.org page for humble.

The following commands were used to set up the sources.

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update && sudo apt install curl -y
sudo curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key -o /usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg
echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu $(. /etc/os-release && echo $UBUNTU_CODENAME) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list > /dev/null
```

The commands above were all successful

Then I proceeded to try and install the ros 2 packages

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

and then:

```
sudo apt install ros-humble-desktop
```

- fail

the same goes with base

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu 20.04 you need to install ROS 2 Galactic, ROS 2 humble works on ubuntu Jammy (22.04).

Comment: @Vladimir did it work? If it did please mark the answer as accepted and if you still have problems please share the info so we can help. :)